# python matplotlib not plotting y axis in order

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am very new to Python - I have a time series that I want to model, but I get stuck early on with simply plotting the time series. The plot seems to be ordering the y-axis in order of the numbers appearing:
[image]

```
plt.plot(model_data2['month'], model_data2['opening_position'], color='blue', linewidth=2)
plt.ylabel('Opening Position ($)')

plt.show()
```

I would greatly appreciate advise on how to correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing strings here, so yes, it assumes you gave them in the order you wanted them. It doesn't know how to plot the value of a string. Convert these to floats, and you will get the results you expect.

Comment: how do I convert it? I tried following the steps here https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html , but no success ....

Comment: dont worry... got it converted... my python versions might be different.